# Can this topology be simplified? [Blender]

Tags: blender, mesh, topology, 3d-modelling

I have a part of mesh as given below. Would like to know if there's a better/lowpoly way to achieve the same result? Also would this be considered a good topology?

The highlighted area is actual needed part of the mesh, rest is my attempt to simplify it.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then check the [help/on-topic] to see which questions are on-topic on this site.
You might want to delete this question and ask it on https://blender.stackexchange.com/ instead, but check the help pages there first.

Comment: @UtkarshBhardwaj  Why did you make it so complicated?? The highlighted area can easily be achieved by adding 4 loop cuts to the mesh.

Comment: I have several patterns like such spread in the mesh. The lines from 4 loop cuts would amount to 6 horizontal and 4 vertical, wrapping around the whole object. Those other patterns would also have other lines running through the object. Overall my polycount for even the easier surfaces would spike. Hence the complicated structure. If I can somehow overcome that issue, I'd be happy with simple loop cuts.

Answer (score 0):

you can inset a face by selecting it then pressing 'i', then moving the mouse to get the desired size.